# How to return the last push() embedded document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm stuck trying to figure out if this is possible.

Using the blog example from mongoose to demonstrate, however my actual use case is slightly more complicated:

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Comments]
});

var BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost');
var post = new BlogPost();
```

I need to create a new comment and return the *new* comment to the client. Having comments as embedded document is really convenient for me and works well. However I don't want to return every single comment to the client each time I add a new one.

```
post.comments.push({ title: 'My comment' });
```

As I'm using mongoose if I could some how get the `id` of the new comment that would help and also allow me to add other functionality such as editing a commenting or deleting a comment.

Is the only way to do this is to have comments as their own collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem you're trying to solve is to how to update the page after a client posts a comment, right?

So, you're inserting a new comment. This means that you already have its data. Perform an insert and return the data to the client. Or, better yet, return a simple ack, since client also has full comment data and can render it by itself.

Comment: That definitely helps however without an `id` of some kind the client can't do anything further with the comment. For example remove it, edit it etc. Can I get the `id` of the new embedded document?

Comment: @Tom: embedded documents don't have ids. Unless you assign them yourself. But then DB doesn't do any uniqueness checks, it's all on you. You can generate a unique ObjectId in your node.js code.

Comment: Thanks Sergio. I'm using mongoose which adds that sort of magic for you :)

Comment: In the end I passed through to the mongodb-native driver using `var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId.createPk();` to [create an id](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/bson/objectid.js#L167) then assigned it myself as you suggested above. Now I have all the info I need to send to the client. Does that sound ok?

Comment: @Tom: yes, I would do the same.