# Loop over Array inside Loop

Tags: arrays, loops, mongoose

based on this [Mongoose embedded documents / DocumentsArrays id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994670/mongoose-embedded-documents-documentsarrays-id?rq=1) 
i try to implement a condition in a loop inside a loop. At the end, the new "tosave" Comments Object should contain the _id from the BlogPost based on "where a_id = b_id".

I use node,express and mongoose.
I have a multi row form with multiple BlogPosts and a Blogpost can have multiple Comments.

On the Backend, i have 2 Arrays -> BlogPosts and Comments like this:

```
BlogPosts: [{ a_id: '1', name: 'name1' },
            { a_id: '2', name: 'name2' },
            { a_id: '3', name: 'name3' }], 


Comments: [{ b_id: '1', name: 'comment for BlogPost name1' },
           { b_id: '1', name: 'other comment for BlogPost name1' },
           { b_id: '3', name: 'comment for BlogPost name3' }],
```

I need the _id from a Blogpost Document inside every Comment, to reference between Comments and Blogposts.

I loop over the BlogPosts like this:

```
var new_post_to_save = [];

    for(var i=0; i<req.body.blogposts.length;i++) {

       var newpost = new BlogPost();

       console.log('blogpost nr : ' + [i] + ' has new _id: ' + newpost._id );

       newpost.name = req.body.blogposts[i].name,
       newpost.a_id = req.body.blogposts[i].a_id

       new_post_to_save.push(newpost);

     },
```

This is working fine. I get a new Array "new_post_to_save", witch i can save easy.
Now i try to loop inside BlogPosts to give every Comment the _id Field from the new created "newpost" Object.

What i try - but it failed.. It matches all Comments to all BlogPosts.

```
var new_post_to_save = [];
var new_comment_to_save = [];

     for(var i=0; i<req.body.blogposts.length;i++) {

       var newpost = new BlogPost();

       console.log('blogpost nr : ' + [i] + ' has new _id: ' + newpost._id );

       newpost.name = req.body.blogposts[i].name,
       newpost.a_id = req.body.blogposts[i].a_id

       // here a loop to create x Comments with the _id from newpost and 
       // the condition: IF a_id = b_id 
       // then create new Comment and get die _id from his Blogpost

       for(var f=0; f<req.body.comments.length;f++) {

         if (newpost.a_id = req.body.comments[f].b_id) 
         console.log(' Yea ! Comment ' + [f] + ' matches Blogpost Nr. ' + [i]);

          var newcomment = new CommentModel();

          newcomment.id_newpost = newpost._id,
          newcomment.name = req.body.comments[f].name,
          newcomment.b_id = req.body.comments[f].b_id,       
        };  // end if
     };   // end for


    new_comment_to_save.push(newcomment);
    new_post_to_save.push(newpost);

      },    // end for
```

This is my first question here.

Any ideas ? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familair with Mongoose, just looking at your code, seems you have a little mistake in code: position of: new_comment_to_save.push(newcomment);    it should be in the if because only when they match you want them added..

```
var new_post_to_save = [];
var new_comment_to_save = [];
 for(var i=0; i<req.body.blogposts.length;i++) {

   var newpost = new BlogPost();

   console.log('blogpost nr : ' + [i] + ' has new _id: ' + newpost._id );

   newpost.name = req.body.blogposts[i].name,
   newpost.a_id = req.body.blogposts[i].a_id

   // here a loop to create x Comments with the _id from newpost and 
   // the condition: IF a_id = b_id 
   // then create new Comment and get die _id from his Blogpost

   for(var f=0; f<req.body.comments.length;f++) {

     if (newpost.a_id = req.body.comments[f].b_id) 
     console.log(' Yea ! Comment ' + [f] + ' matches Blogpost Nr. ' + [i]);

      var newcomment = new CommentModel();

      newcomment.id_newpost = newpost._id,
      newcomment.name = req.body.comments[f].name,
      newcomment.b_id = req.body.comments[f].b_id,
      new_comment_to_save.push(newcomment);       
    };  // end if
 };   // end for



new_post_to_save.push(newpost);

  },    // end for
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was this and the = should be ==.